# Change Metronic Angular to work with Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, metronic

I've been usgin angular version of [Metronic](https://keenthemes.com/metronic/?page=docs) to make a angular admin. I put the conections to firebase on **enviroment.ts** and **enviroment.prod.ts** after install

```
npm install firebase @angular/fire --save

export const environment = {
  production: true,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://xxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    appId: "1:xxxxxxxxx:web:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    measurementId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
};
```

as documentation says, Im also change the line on file:

**src/app/modules/_services/auth-http/index.ts**

from

```
export { AuthHTTPService } from './auth-fake-http.service'; // You have to comment this, when your real back-end is done
```

to

```
export { AuthHTTPService } from './auth-http.service'; // You have to uncomment this, when your real back-end is done
```

and comment the lines on app.module.ts

```
environment.isMockEnabled
      ? HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(FakeAPIService, {
          passThruUnknownUrl: true,
          dataEncapsulation: false,
        })
      : [],
```

aldo in app.module.ts I import the library

```
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
```

and on ngModules I insert:

```
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
```

but it still dont have the login working

Someone knows what I still have to do to have it working on Metronic angular admin version

Thanks for helping

Comment: What is the error you're seeing?

Comment: Metronic template has environment property `isMockEnabled`, so you don't have to comment out code `HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot...`